# firebase call/trigger functions run like transaction (one after another)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

What I want is simple and easy, but I don't know if it is possible to do it.

**Func 1:**

```js
exports.readProducts = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    //SOME CODE
});
```

**Func 2:**

```js
exports.onCountChange=functions.database.ref('/ANALYTICS/count').onWrite((change, context) => {
    //SOME CODE
});
```

I want this 2 functions to run like transaction, so if 2 people call/change the value at the same time, it should run one call at the time.

Comment: It's not possible to make cloud function invocations happen in order or block one another, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson, it is impossible to make the cloud functions invocations happen in sequence or block another.

Additionally, here is a [Google group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk) that you can use for anything related to firebase.